# Get unique array values across multiple CosmosDB documents

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have documents with a "Cedent" field that is an array of strings. When I run this query:

`SELECT DISTINCT c.Cedents FROM c`

I get the following result:

```
[
    {
        "Cedents": [
            "Test 1",
            "Test 2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Cedents": [
            "Test 1",
            "Test 3"
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a way to get only the unique values across all documents, as a single array? Example:

```
[
    {
        "Cedents": [
            "Test 1",
            "Test 2",
            "Test 3"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for example:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE x
FROM x IN c.Cedents
```

This iterates each array element and gets the distinct values.

Result:

```json
[
    "Test 1",
    "Test 2",
    "Test 3"
]
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-object-array#Iteration

Comment: I don't think this works. Counting the results returns an order of magnitude too high a number:
 SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT VALUE x FROM x IN c.Cedents)

Comment: @MichaelBöckling SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT VALUE x FROM x IN c.Cedents)